# Super simple composite key without @EmbeddedId or @IdClass

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, join

I don't know since when this is possible, but I just created composite keys the way I always wanted: No `@EmbeddedId` and no `@IdClass` required!!

- Spring 4.0.0.M3
- Hibernate 4.3.0.Beta4
- JPA 2.1

**User.java**:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<GroupUser> groupUsers;     
}
```

**Group.java**:

```
@Entity
public class Group {
    @Id
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<GroupUser> groupUsers;     
}
```

**GroupUser.java**:

```
@Entity
public class GroupUser implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Group_id")
    private Group group;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="User_id")
    private User user;

    @Id
    @Column
    private String s;

    @Column
    private int i;
}
```

And here is what MySQL says:

```
 USER             GROUP_USER            GROUP
------    -------------------------    -------
 id        User_id  (PK, NOT NULL)       id 
           Group_id (PK, NOT NULL)
           s        (PK, NOT NULL)
           i        (DEFAULT NULL)
```

`GROUP_USER` details:

- PRIMARY KEY: User_id, Group_id, s
- INDEX #1 / FOREIGN KEY: User_id
- INDEX #2 / FOREIGN KEY: Group_id

---

I also did some other tests, like this:

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    String a;

    @Id
    @Column
    String b;

    @Column
    String c;

}
```

Works like a charm!!

---

Is there still any reason to use `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass`?

And: Is this part of JPA 2.1 or an Hibernate feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA requires a primary key class of some sort be defined for composite primary keys.  In practice though, this seems required mostly for the EntityManager find and getReference calls that require a pk class instance.  Implementations may have their own pk representation that you can use for these calls, but will not be portable.

Comment: Okay. That sounds like it must be a Hibernate feature. But that's not bad at all, the project heavily depends on JBoss/Hibernate technology.

Comment: You still might want to define a key class, as it defines the contract to use for find and getReference, making it clear in the entity for future reuse.

Comment: Would you use `@EmbeddedId` or `@IdClass`? `@IdClass` looks more simple, is there any disadvantage?

Comment: BTW: Here's the answer to my question (under *2.2.3.2. Composite identifier*): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier There's said: *map multiple properties as @Id properties: the identifier type is then the entity class itself and needs to be Serializable. This approach is unfortunately not standard and only supported by Hibernate.*

Comment: EmbeddedId basically caches the pk class instance within the entity.  This is extra overhead/abstraction IMO that isn't necessary if you rarely use it.  EclipseLink I believe also allows not defining a PK class, taking its own CacheKey representation or a list of pk values as the key instead.

Comment: I really can't decide. It seems pretty useless to me to define the underlying type of the referenced object's id again and again. Too bad those JPA guys never think about easy and useful solutions ;)