# Is there a way to delete a child entity in a @OneToMany relationship (with a JoinTable) without having to fetch the full collection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, spring-data

I've got the following classes/relationship (getters & setters not displayed, but present):

```
public class Contract implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    private String number;
    private String volume;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attachment_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
}

public class Attachment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(length=2147483647)
    private byte[] contents;


    private String name;
}
```

As per my needs/design, I am using a join table.

If I want to delete an attachment from the Contract, I need to load the Contract, and then loop through all the attachments until I find the one I want to remove and remove it from the list.

Although this is functional, it will require a lot of DB communication.  If the list of attachments is long, and contains large contents, it will also require large bandwidth.

Is there any other way I can remove it?  If I try to remove the attachment directly (ex: Attachment.findById().delete()), it will fail due to the FK relationship - won't it?  (I haven't tried this yet, but I suspect it).

Additionally, if I have a very large list of attachments, iterating through them one by one until I find the correct one is not very efficient either.

Does JPA provide any other/better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one workaround solution I know - you can create an entity class for join table.

You will have to give a name to your join table within `@JoinTable` annotation (*name* attribute), lets say `ContractAttachment`. Then you can create entity:

```
@Entity(name = "ContractAttachment") // note the same name of table
@IdClass(ContractAttachmentId.class)
public class ContractAttachment implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="contract_id") // same mappings for columns
    private Contract contract;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="attachment_id") // same mappings for columns
    private Attachment attachment;

    // you will also have to override equals and hashcode methods here

}
```

The class `ContractAttachmentId` should look like:

```
public class ContractAttachmentId implements Serializable {
    private long contract; // note the same fields names
    private long attachment;

    // this class should also implement hashcode and equals
}
```

Now you can remove a single entry in join table and even cause attachment object to be deleted too.

```
ContractAttachment ca = em.createQuery("select ca from ContractAttachment ca " +
        "where ca.contract = :contract and ca.attachment = :attachment")
        .setParameter("contract", selectedContract)
        .setParameter("attachement", selectedAttachment)
        .getSingleResult();
em.remove(ca);
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  But won't there be a conflict when JPA creates the join table as part of the relationship and then tries to create the same table for the entity?  I have the feeling that I had tried that already and ran into that problem, but I may not have had the '@JoinColumn' annotations in place.  I'll have to try it again.

Comment: I used this solution many times and did not run into any problems. The key is to correctly map both entities `Contract` and `Attachement` and do the same mapping (column names and table name) in `ContractAttachment`. You do not have to use this entity until you need to (in case you specified), but I think it is nice to just have one. JPA will not create table which already exists, so it will be ok.

Comment: Are you also required to have an `@IdClass` defined due to the composite PK?  Or is there a way around that?  I'm getting compile time errors requiring me to specify a composite PK id class.  Can you post an example of an IdClass? I'm having trouble getting this to compile successfully.

Comment: Okay, I just found out why it is working for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009572/super-simple-composite-key-without-embeddedid-or-idclass .To be honest, I don't know if there's simple solution to workaround this using other providers. I would start with creating `@Embedabble` class with `Contract` and `Attachment` relationships and then declare it as `@EmbeddedId` in `ContractAttachment` class.

Comment: I got this to work, except that manipulating the join table directly like this is not thread safe; given that it does not modify the `@Version` field of the Contract entity, any other thread that already has a Contract entity loaded will not know that the data is stale.  And to manually update the version field and persist the Contract will just overwrite my changes to the join table.  So the only way I can think of is to use a raw sql to update the version field so persisting an existing Contract object would fail.  Is there a better way?

Comment: wait, why do you have separate entity for one-to-many association? If FK was stored in Attachment table, then mentioned by you `Attachment.findById().delete()` would work as expected.

Comment: By design, I am using a separate entity/join table as my `Attachment` object is reused in several entities (`Contract` is just one example of it).  Consequently, I do not want the FK stored in the attachment table.

Comment: @EricB. I have just updated an answer, it should now work with any JPA provider.