# Inserting to a link table without fetching first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a Task table (called Task_Task) and a Field table (called Core_Field). I also have Task_Field table that links the two in many to many relationship:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task_Field](
        [TaskId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [FieldId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Task_Field] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [TaskId] ASC,
        [FieldId] ASC
    ))
```

I need to insert a number of records into this table. I'm doing it like this:

```
dbTask.Core_Field.Clear();
List<Core_Field> dbFields = _context.Core_Field
   .Where(x => fields.Contains(x.FieldId)).ToList();                
foreach (var field in dbFields)
{
    dbTask.Core_Field.Add(field);
}
```

This leads to the following trace:

[image]

In this case we had 5 guids in `List<Guid> fields`. The reason we see this insane value (that's the time the query took to run), is because the rows in the Core_Field table are very wide. They have a few binary fields with a lot of data. If I don't retrieve these fields, but do something like this instead:

```
var tmp = _context.Core_Field
    .Where(x =>fields.Contains(x.FieldId))
    .Select(x => x.SomeField).ToList();
```

The time drops from ~1000ms to just a few ms, in most cases zero.

As you can see *inserting* the records does not take long either.

Now, I do not need the whole row from that table. Heck, I don't need *anything* from that table, I already have all the guids to be inserted.

This is what EF relationship looks like:

[image]

I would like to know, how to add these records to the link table efficiently. I, of course, can always run [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand%28System.String,System.Object[]%29) method, and do update without using task or field entities, but I was wondering if there is more EF - idiomatic way of doing this.

Comment: You just need to insert records in Task_Field? Why don't you create objects of that type and insert them?

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein There is no type that represents this object. See the diagram at the bottom of the question to visualize how EF models this relationship.

Comment: If you need to insert the relationship the way you described you'll need to create a class to assciate Field and Task. Also, that class could have extra information about the relationship, giving you more flexibility.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein, well this is Database First. Changing the EF model generated from the database is usually undesirable, since it makes it difficult to propagate any future database schema changes to the model.

Comment: I think you can do 2 things: 1) create a SP and call it passing the pair IDs (field and task). 2) create the mapping class and map it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line of code...

```
dbTask.Core_Field.Add(field)
```

...the `dbTask.Core_Field` is loaded due to lazy loading.

You'll see a major performance gain if you disable lazy loading:

```
_context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

But, since you "already have all the guids to be inserted", you can gain even more (albeit much less) by using *stub entities*, entities only having an Id value. After all, EF only needs the Id values to create the associations:

```
List<Core_Field> dbFields = fields.Select(f => new Core_Field { FieldId = f }).ToList();

 foreach (var field in dbFields)
{
    _context.Core_Fields.Attach(field);
    dbTask.Core_Field.Add(field);
}
```

One caveat: because of disabled lazy loading, EF isn't tracking the `dbTask.Core_Field` any more. That means that it no longer spots duplicates. With lazy loading, EF would just ignore duplicate junction records. Without it, you will get duplicate key errors if you try to insert duplicates. So you may want to check for that beforehand:

```
fields = _context.Code_Tasks
                 .Where(t => t.TaskId == id)
                 .SelectMany(t => t.Core_Field)
                 .Where(c => !fields.Contains(c.FieldId))
                 .Select(c => c.FieldId).ToList();
```

This is a relatively light-weight query.

Comment: Right on the money. Thanks. Note that lazy loading is only a problem if the task already exists. If it's being inserted as a part of the same transaction I do not observe the lazy loading in the profiler.

Comment: Ah yes, I got a bit confused in the table names. In this case it's the stub entities that save the show.

Comment: I'm actually using this same code for both insert and update so all good. I was wondering if you could help with one more facet of this problem. Right before this code I had this line `dbTask.Core_Field.Clear();` - to remove old set of fields associated with the task. This code now does not result in a db call (with lazy loading switched off). How can I restore this functionality?

Comment: Rats! That's much harder. I happened to [answer this yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31641672/861716) for one entity, but you can apply the same trick to a collection of entities. In your case I lean to executing a raw SQL statement that deletes all junction records of one task.